# Autofill from Last row of a column till Last row of the entire sheet

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

[image]

Here I want to auto fill from B6 to B10.
B5 is the last row of Column B and A10 is the last row of entire sheet.

Currently i am using the following code.

```
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Last As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row    'Last row from entire sheet

Last = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row      'Last row of Column B +1

Range(Last & Lastrow).Formula = "4"


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This works if i am using

```
Range(B6:B & Lastrow).Formula = "4"
```

But This might not be helpful if the last rows changes

Comment: Do you really need last row of the sheet? Do you know that the last row exists in "A:A" column? The last row of the sheet my exist in "C:C", for instance and it can be determined in a different way. I mean, something global, independent of the column where this last row is filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range(B6:B & Lastrow).Formula = "4"
```

Change to

```
Range("B" & last & ":B" & Lastrow) = "4"
```

Answer (score 1):

The next code will do what you required, referring the real last cell **of the sheet**, independent of the column where it exists:

```
  Dim LastrowSh As Long, LastB As Long

  LastrowSh = ActiveSheet.cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 'Last row from entire sheet
  LastB = Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row            'Last row of Column B + 1

  Range("B" & LastB, "B" & LastrowSh).value = "4"
```